# Switching from development to production in rails 3.2.6

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have rails app which uses Rails 3.2.6 & Ruby 1.9.3p0 version.I have number of CSS & JS(using JQuery) files in my assets folder with assets pipeline.Everything works fine but I switch from **development to production with compression** to single file named application.css & application.js then my most of **JQuery code don't working**. I have tried many solutions present but nothing helps me.

Please help.Thanks in advance.

This is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tritinum   <%#= controller.action_name %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-     ui.min.js", "jquery.rails.js" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700'%>

<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<!-- BEGIN MAIN -->

<section id="main" class="container_16">
<p class="notice"><%#= notice %></p>
   <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>


    <%= yield %>


 <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
      <section class="footer">

        <p>
<span class="left">�Copyright 2012 - All rights reserved.  </span>
   <span class="right">Web Tool v1.0 - Product By<a href="http://www.google.com">Personal.</a></span>
        </p>

        <div class="clear"></div><!-- CLEAR BOTH -->

    </section><!-- end section .footer -->
    <!-- END FOOTER -->

        </section><!-- end section #main -->
     <!-- END MAIN -->

    <!-- BEGIN LOADING OVERLAY -->
    <div id="loading_overlay">
    <div class="loading_message round_bottom">
        <%= image_tag "loading.gif" %>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END LOADING OVERLAY -->
       </body>
   </html>
```

application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
 # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
 Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
 # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
 # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
  end

module Tritinum
class Application < Rails::Application
# Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
# Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
# -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

# Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
# :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
# config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

# Activate observers that should always be running.
# config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
# config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de

# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
config.filter_parameters += [:password]

# Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
# This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
# like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
# config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

# Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
# This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
# in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
# parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

# Enable the asset pipeline
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
 # config.assets.precompile = ['*.css']
# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
   config.assets.version = '1.0'
 end
 end
```

production.rb

```
 Tritinum::Application.configure do
 # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

 # Code is not reloaded between requests
 config.cache_classes = true

 # C hoose the compressors to use
 config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
   config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

 # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
    config.serve_static_assets = false

   # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
   config.assets.compress = false

   # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
    config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
      config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
    # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

      # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure    cookies.
    # config.force_ssl = true

      # See everything in the log (default is :info)
      # config.log_level = :debug

       # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
    # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

       # Use a different logger for distributed setups
        # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

        # Use a different cache store in production
           # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

          # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
          # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

       # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
      # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

      # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
         # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

        # Enable threaded mode
              # config.threadsafe!

       # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
        # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
        config.i18n.fallbacks = true

    #  Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
        config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

          # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
           # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
             # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
         end
```

While, i am starting rails server in production after compiling with this command

```
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

most of my JQuery code stops working.

Gemfile

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

 gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
 gem 'haml'

 # Bundle edge Rails instead:
 # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'faker'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem "nested_form", :git => 'https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'



 # Gems used only for assets and not required
 # in production environments by default.
 group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

 # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

 gem 'jquery-rails'

 # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

      # To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
      # gem 'jbuilder'

     # Use unicorn as the app server
       # gem 'unicorn'

      # Deploy with Capistrano
      # gem 'capistrano'

     # To use debugger
      # gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js file

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the  bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
  function remove_fields(link) {
    $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
    $(link).up(".fields").hide();
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#finding_category_id").change(function(){
        var id_value_string = $(this).val();
        if (id_value_string == "") {
            // if the id is empty remove all the sub_selection options from being selectable and do not do any ajax
            $("select#finding_finding_template_id option").remove();
            var row = "<option value=\"" + "" + "\">" + "" + "</option>";
            $(row).appendTo("select#finding_finding_template_id");
         }
        else {
            // Send the request and update sub category dropdown
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                url: '/finding_templates/for_categoryid/' + id_value_string,
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorTextStatus, error){
                    alert("Failed to submit : "+ errorTextStatus+" ;"+error);
                },
                success: function(data){                    
                    // Clear all options from sub category select
                    $("select#finding_finding_template_id option").remove();
                    //put in a empty default line
                    var row = "<option value=\"" + "Select" + "\">" + "" + "</option>";
                    $(row).appendTo("select#finding_finding_template_id");                        
                    // Fill sub category select
                    $.each(data, function(i, j){
                        row = "<option value=\"" + j.finding_template.id + "\">" +          j.finding_template.name + "</option>";  
                        $(row).appendTo("select#finding_finding_template_id");                    
                    });            
                 }
            });
        };
            });
  });
```

Please somone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

^ That line in your `application.rb` is to tell the precompile function to precompile lazily. This means that it will precompile assets only in your main application.  If you set this to true, it will be able to pre-compile assets included in other referenced Gems. So unless you have the `jquery` files explicitly **in** your application's assets folder, it is probably getting missed on pre-compilation - thus it is not included in your `application.js`.

**NOTE**

This line: `config.assets.compile = true` should tell your application to fall back to the assets pipeline if a pre-compiled asset is missed - **ideally** this would mean that it would find the jquery asset from the normal pipeline.

However my guess is that since **technically** it does find `application.js`, your application is not aware that there has been a missed asset, so it loads the pre-compiled `application.js` and then there is just no way it can get the `jquery` code.

**Solution**

Sorry for long-winded explanation, but please try the following - Set the following line in your `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile
```

to be `true`

And then you'll of course have to rebuild and redeploy :) Let me know if this helps!!

Comment: By rebuild I just mean you'll have to restart (sorry, I use maven to package a WAR file)

Essentially, if you are running it locally, you need to restart the rails server, and if you are running it in production mode, you need to create a new WAR file

Answer (score 0):

The gem `jquery-rails` already has `jquery-ui.min.js`

you just need add this rows to `assets/javascript/application.js` file

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs`

and has only this line in `application.html.erb`

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Comment: so i ve to remove `jquery-ui.min.js` from `application.html.erb`  and add this `//= require jquery //= require jquery_ujs` to `application.js`

Comment: i already ve these in my `application.js` & i change my `appliction.html.erb` to have this line `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Comment: Please provide me the feasible way to this problem.